# CoffeeScript - load lib with AMD or in the window object (classic way)

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, amd

```
do ((context, lib)->
  console.log context
  console.log lib

)(this, (context, lib)->
  console.log context
  lib_ = context.lib

  lib.version = '0.1'
  return lib
)
```

I want to be able to load `lib` either with amd or in the `window` object. 
I manage to get the wanted result but has an error because of the last set of paranteses `()`
The generated JavaScript code :

```
(function(context, lib) {
  console.log(context);
  return console.log(lib);

})(this, function(context, lib) {
  console.log(context);

  var lib_ = context.lib;
  lib.version = '0.1';
  return lib;

})(); // this last set of paranteses cause an error
```

I tried to write the CoffeeScript to generate JS this way also :     (with no succes)

```
(function(context, lib) {
  console.log(context);
  return console.log(lib);

}(this, function(context, lib) {
  console.log(context);

  var lib_ = context.lib;
  lib.version = '0.1';
  return lib;
}));
```

From what i know it's posssible to write JS code in CoffeeScript to bypass this issue but i would like that to be the last option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `do` from the first line, the output looks like this:

```
(function(context, lib) {
  console.log(context);
  return console.log(lib);
})(this, function(context, lib) {
  var lib_;
  console.log(context);
  lib_ = context.lib;
  lib.version = '0.1';
  return lib;
});
```

So, **[CS](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%28%28context,%20lib%29-%3E%0A%20%20console.log%20context%0A%20%20console.log%20lib%0A%0A%29%28this,%20%28context,%20lib%29-%3E%0A%20%20console.log%20context%0A%20%20lib_%20=%20context.lib%0A%0A%20%20lib.version%20=%20%270.1%27%0A%20%20return%20lib%0A%29)**:

```
((context, lib)->
  console.log context
  console.log lib

)(this, (context, lib)->
  console.log context
  lib_ = context.lib

  lib.version = '0.1'
  return lib
)
```

Comment: i tried a lot of weird combinations ... i really fell ashamed. Thanks

Comment: So, @BogdanVolosincu, can I conclude that this works for you?